# Ruby object's console view beautifier - is there something like that?

Tags: ruby, irb

In Ruby console we can show an object in a form like that:

```
#<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemcachedStore:0x00005649aedceb20 @swallow_exceptions=true, @options={:namespace
=>"dfw_cache", :codec=>#<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemcachedStore::Codec:0x00005649aedce8f0 @serializer=
Marshal, @compressor=nil>}, @connection=#<Memcached: ...
```

Although for large objects this form is almost impossible to read. Are there some beautifiers available for objects in these notation?

Comment: `pp` is auto required depending on your Ruby version.

Comment: The awesome_print gem is often a good option, but your mileage may vary.